# Regular expression, pick first numbers from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string

```
var str = "14⊰Ⓟ⊱ 7⊰➆Ⓑ⊱ 12⊰Ⓢ⊱ 7⊰➆Ⓑ⊱";
```

and I need to pick first numbers in string(14, 7, 12, 7).

I wrote code the following code, but this code picks numbers separated (1, 4, 7, 1, 2, 7):

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    newStr = str.match(/\d/g);
}
```

Comment: *"and I need to pick first numbers in string(14, 7, 12, 7)."* No, the **first** number is 14. Do you mean the first number in each group?

Comment: Why would you expect `\d` to match a two-digit number? The MDN regexp intro clearly states "`\d`:  
Matches **a digit character**." That intro and any other would also cover the basic `+` quantifier for matching one or more of something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **problem** with your regex is that it is missing `+` quantifier after `\d`. `\d` will match only one number.

You can use `\d+` to match all numbers. The `+` quantifier will match one or more of the previous class.

Alternately, you can also use `[0-9]+`.

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sM8aC5/1)

```js
var str = '14⊰Ⓟ⊱ 7⊰➆Ⓑ⊱ 12⊰Ⓢ⊱ 7⊰➆Ⓑ⊱';
var matches = str.match(/\d+/g);

console.log(matches);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(matches, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I was about to answer, but then thought an edit in your answer would be better. Feel free to reject if you think this does not improve answer.

Answer (score 1):

That loop looks redundant, unless you omitted something from copypaste.
String object's [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method returns an array, not a string.

```
var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g);
```

Gives you a following array: `["14", "7", "12", "7"]`.

You may further cast matches to integers by:

```
numbers = numbers.map(function(n) { return parseInt(n); });
```

#### Example

```js
var str = "14⊰Ⓟ⊱ 7⊰➆Ⓑ⊱ 12⊰Ⓢ⊱ 7⊰➆Ⓑ⊱";
var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g).map(function(n) { return parseInt(n); });
// or as Tushar pointed out:
var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(numbers) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: The last line can be written as `numbers.map(Number);`

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that. Much clearer and unambiguous.